# Unexpected Token in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am getting the following error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
SyntaxError: /vagrant/resources/assets/js/react/react_app.js: Unexpected token (366:10)
  364 | var InvestorsTable = React.createClass({
  365 | 
> 366 |     mixins: [Polling, StateHandler, ComponentBase],
      |           ^
  367 | 
  368 |     render: function() {
  369 |         return(
    at Parser.pp.raise (/vagrant/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:24:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/vagrant/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:82:8)
    at Parser.pp.expect (/vagrant/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:76:33)
    at Parser.pp.jsxParseExpressionContainer (/vagrant/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:301:8)
    at Parser.pp.jsxParseElementAt (/vagrant/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:370:30)
    at Parser.pp.jsxParseElementAt (/vagrant/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:362:30)
    at Parser.pp.jsxParseElement (/vagrant/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:398:15)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (/vagrant/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:410:21)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/vagrant/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:236:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/vagrant/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:217:19)
```

This error is caused by the following code:

```
var InvestorsTable = React.createClass({

    mixins: [Polling, StateHandler, ComponentBase],

    render: function() {
        return(
            <Table data={this.state.data} />
        );
    }
});
```

How is this invalid syntax? Where is my "unexpected token"? I have another class:

```
var CapitalRaised = React.createClass({

    mixins: [Polling, StateHandler, ComponentBase],

    ...

});
```

This class doesn't throw an error when its compiled and its compiled **BEFORE** the above class. Like I **can't see** what the issue is ....

Comment: Maybe check for weird non-visible Unicode characters that may be lurking in there. That can sometimes happen in cut/paste scenarios.

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess, you have an unclosed JSX element farther up in your file above this point, and the `{` on line 364 is switching the JSX parser from JSX Text to JS parsing, `mixins:` is being parsed as a LabelledStatement. https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1885#issuecomment-117422784 I'll elaborate in an answer if you verify I'm right.

Answer (score 4):

You have an unclosed JSX element father up above in your file above that class. Since you haven't shown your full code, here is an example.

```
var CapitalRaised = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return (<div>);
  }
});

var InvestorsTable = React.createClass({

  mixins: [Polling, StateHandler, ComponentBase],

  render: function() {
    return(
      <Table data={this.state.data} />
    );
  }
});
```

The `<div>` element is not closed. This will throw `Unexpected token (9:8)` because JSX takes the form of `<div> ... { mixins: [Polling` and in JSX, content inside `{}` is supposed to be a JS expression, and `mixins:` is not a valid start to an expressions.